# GRUB on EFI system does not automatically load grub.conf

Tags: linux, boot, grub, uefi, grub2-mkconfig

After a Rocky Linux migration (pun intended) no bootloader was found when booting. Booting in rescue mode from a USB drive, I was able to restore a GRUB prompt when booting normally. From that prompt, I can get to a fully functional system with this GRUB command :

```
configfile (hdo,3)/efi/rocky/grub.conf
```

When doing so, I get these options, which match the content of `/boot/loader/entries` :

[image: kernel options selection menu]

After hours of searching, I have been unable to get the GRUB configuration to load by itself.

At the GRUB prompt, executing `set` yields this :

[image: GRUB set output]

On the booted system the listing of my /boot/efi/EFI is this :

[image: EFI directory listing]

I am unable to figure out why GRUB does not automatically execute the `grub.conf` file which is located in the rocky directory and works when invoked by the `configfile` GRUB command.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem by re-executing simple instructions I had previously found and tried.

```
yum reinstall grub2-efi shim
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/rocky/grub.cfg
```

There must be something I have done along the way that finally allowed these to work.